# Postman test to find a keyword in a response array

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I am creating a test in postman to check for a keyword "pregnancy" in each "name" field in the JSON. If each 'name' field in the JSON contains the keyword then pass the test, else fail.

Find the script below that I have tried using

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 

var resultCount = jsonData.length;
for (i=0;i<resultCount;i++){
    var modelString = jsonData[i].name;
    if(modelString.indexOf("Pregnancy") > 0)
    {
       tests["Each organisation name field " +i+ " contains   \"Pregnancy\""] = modelString.has("Pregnancy");
    }
    else
    {
       pm.expect.fail("failed");
    }
}
console.log("")

[
    {
        "id": "1-116992830",
        "name": "British Pregnancy Advisory Service      (BPAS)",
        "numberOfLocations": 78
    },
    {
        "id": "1-1560082724",
        "name": "PAMS Pregnancy Ultrasound Centre      (PAMS 3D &     4D Baby Imaging)",
        "numberOfLocations": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "1-2458518720",
        "name": "Pregnancy Ultrasound Ltd      (Babyface4d)",
        "numberOfLocations": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "1-101728376",
        "name": "National Unplanned Pregnancy Advisory Service     Limited",
        "numberOfLocations": 23
    },
    {
        "id": "1-3578030817",
        "name": "Private Pregnancy Ultrasound Services Ltd trading as Expectancy Scanning Studios Ltd      (Expectancy Scanning Studios Ltd)",
        "numberOfLocations": 2
    },
    {
        "id": "1-1412821832",
        "name": "Foundation For Life (Salisbury)      (Pregnancy Advice Salisbury)",
        "numberOfLocations": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "1-2028907839",
        "name": "Miscarriage Clinic Limited      (Centre for     Reproductive Immunolgy and Pregnancy)",
        "numberOfLocations": 1
    },
    {
        "id": "1-744810951",
        "name": "Foundation For Life      (Tyneside Pregnancy Advice Centre)",
        "numberOfLocations": 1
    }
]
```

What I'm expecting is, if 'pregnancy' is missing from the each array field, it should fail the test

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I would start with transforming the search query and the string you're testing to lowercase, so that the indexOf method works for both 'Pregnancy' and 'pregnancy'. Also, the string 'pregnancy' can be at index 0, so you should check if it is larger than -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added your JSON to https://api.myjson.com/bins/13qh7i to create an API to test with under Postman, and added one additional object in the array with a name that doesn't have the word "pregnancy" in it so you can see the test in action.

If you loop through and check the `objects` `name` property for the word "pregnancy", and store those that are found in the `hasPregnancy` `array`, you can then check the `length` of the `array` against the `length` of the API response `object array` to see if each `object` indeed contains the keyword "pregnancy".

Below is the JS code I used in the test. I also updated your `indexOf` to be `includes` since you should be looking for `> -1 with indexOf`. I also made the `modelString` variable apply `toLowerCase()` on the `name` to ensure checking doesn't care about capitalization, etc.

[image]

```js
// Get response
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var resultCount = jsonData.length;

// Test arrays
var hasPregnancy = [];
var doesntHavePregnancy = [];

// Loop through and set arrays with matching data
for (i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
  var id = jsonData[i].id;
  var modelString = jsonData[i].name.toLowerCase();
  if (modelString.includes("pregnancy")) {
    hasPregnancy.push({
      "id": id,
      "hasPregnancy": modelString.has("pregnancy")
    });
  } else {
    doesntHavePregnancy.push({
      "id": id
    });
  }
}

// Check that each object in response contained keyword and length matches from test
pm.test("Expect response to contain pregnancy in each object", function() {
  console.log(hasPregnancy);
  console.log(doesntHavePregnancy);
  pm.expect(hasPregnancy.length).to.equal(resultCount);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept answer if it worked for you. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this has helped me as well.. question what if  want a number count of the ones that have Pregnancy and a number count of those that don't have pregnancy .. because in my test i want to get the id of the ones that contain it as not all objects will contain it...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the ES6 reduce function that accumulates the results of whether the name of each item includes "Pregnancy" while iterating through the response.

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
tests[`Each organisation name field contains \"Pregnancy\"`] = jsonData
  .reduce((acc, org) => acc && org.name.toLowerCase().includes("pregnancy"));
```

- You'll find that ES6 functions like map and reduce are generally more expressive
- Using `inlcudes` makes your intention clearer than `indexOf`
- I added `toLowerCase()` so the matches are case insensitive

[image: Passing postman test]

[image: Failing postman test]